# empty column items get filled instead of stay empty

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

In React I'm merging two arrays for a table output. Merging went fine, so far, but when I want to manipulate specific objects inside the map function they also fill the empty table items because the other array is bigger?

So in the example output below the text 'test a..' keep filling the empty column items of price 1 column. What I want is to keep them empty.

```js
class TableForm extends React.Component  {

  get marketData()  {

    const arr1 = [
      {symbol: 'CAT', price_a: 40},
      {symbol: 'DOG', price_a: 50}
    ];
    const arr2 = [
      {symbol: 'CAT', price_b: 25},
      {symbol: 'DOG', price_b: 30},
      {symbol: 'ETC', price_b: 70},
      {symbol: 'BLA', price_b: 20}
    ];

    let arr = [...arr1, ...arr2];

    let combine = arr.reduce((a, { symbol, ...obj }) => {
      a[symbol] = a[symbol] || { symbol };
      Object.assign(a[symbol], obj);
      return a;
    }, {});

    let format = Object.values(combine)

    let markets = format.map((i, k) => {
      return (
        <tr key={k}>
          <td>{i.symbol}</td>
          <td>{i.price_a} test a..</td>
          <td>{i.price_b} test b..</td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
    return markets;
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>symbol</th>
              <th>price 1</th>
              <th>price 2</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.marketData}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TableForm />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what do you want to do? Do you want to hide the column where price1 is empty ?

Comment: I think yes that is basically what I want. so that the text 'test a..' doesn't appear there. because in this case the price 2 column is bigger so price 1 also gets extended ( what i think ).

Comment: Something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/224328/ ?

Comment: yeah thats very nice, how can i put jsx in between? like <span>a</span> ??

Answer (score 0):

You are deploying data every time in the loop like `<td>{i.price_a} test a..</td>`.
here if **i.price_a** not found in the object that means it is undefined, so its rendering like `<td>{undefined} test a..</td>`.

undefined will not reflect in jsx and you will see just `<td>test a..</td>`.

To resolve this issue you can check every object if data found only then the part of td will rendered otherwise it goes black.

i.e.

```
<td>{i.price_a ? `${i.price_a} test a..` : ''} </td>
```

OR

```
<td>{i.price_a ? i.price_a + 'test a..' : ''} </td>
```